# C# Documenting in non XML

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In C# you can add comments with [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkxs89c5(v=vs.71).aspx) tags. Visual studio will use the comments inside its auto complete so you see a nice overview of the method.

```
///<summary>
///summary description
///</summary>
public void Method1() { }
```

I find the above way a little bit to verbose... It seems there is also another way. I have seen this used inside the Unity 3D Engine. But when I try to copy it Visual Studio wont auto complete with the info provided inside the comment block. Here is how Unity does it:

```
//
// Summary:
//     ///
//     summary description
//     ///
public void Method1()
```

Does anyone know why the above 'code' is not working?

Comment: Because it's just Unity which accepts it...

Comment: Where do you see comments like that in unity? Are you clicking "Go to definition" on a method and looking at the "metadata view" of a function?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Indeed

Comment: Based on [previously-asked questions](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/705296/how-can-i-add-a-summary-to-a-function-void.html) and [existing resources out there](http://www.joshuawinn.com/unity-tip-for-mono-develop-comment-function-parameters-with-xml/), the prescribed way of adding summary comments in C# (including Unity/MonoDevelop) is by using XML. You can use any other ways you want...but don't expect them to be supported by many IDEs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the metadata view you are not looking at the actual code. What it is doing is reading the DLL and building the text up to display for you in the metadata view.

If you could look at the actual source you would see it too is using the XML tags.